# how can I harmonized columns in a data frame with string and number (getting only numbers)?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to harmonized my df in R. I have a column that has been populated using different formats
eg:

```
    ID       value
    1   first value in 5' = 9 || second value in 20' = 8
    2   first value in 5' = 6 || second value in 20' = 12
    3   5,6
    4   7,8
    5   9  10
```

what I'm trying so far is

```
     library(stringr)
     df <- read.table("data", sep="\t", header = T)
     value2 <- df$value %>% str_match_all("[0-9]+") %>% unlist %>% as.numeric
```

I expect this output

```
    ID       value
    1        9,8
    2        6,12
    3        5,6
    4        7,8
    5        9,10
```

but obviously, the actual output is an string `[1] 9 8 6 12 5 6 7 8 9 10`

based on your experience, any ideas?
thanks!

Comment: On _Stack Overflow_ it's strongly recommended that you provide `dput(<yourData>)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to split on `||` and use `gsub` to extract the values after `=`. We can then use `toString()` to aggregate them, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

dd %>% 
 separate_rows(value, sep = ' \\|\\| ') %>% 
 mutate(value = gsub('.*=', '', value)) %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 summarise(value = toString(value))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 x 2
>      ID value    
>   <int> <chr>    
> 1     1 " 9,  8" 
> 2     2 " 6,  12"
> 3     3 5,6      
> 4     4 7,8      
> 5     5 9 10
> ```

**EDIT:** To also convert the last space to a comma, we can add another `mutate` to the pipeline, i.e.

```
dd %>% 
     separate_rows(value, sep = ' \\|\\| ') %>% 
     mutate(value = gsub('.*=', '', value)) %>% 
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     summarise(value = toString(value)) %>%
     mutate(value = gsub(' ', ',', value))
```

Comment: I works mostly, but I also need a "," in the last row to separate the numbers. Could you please explain me how to do it? thanks!

Comment: Edited my answer. Have a look